# CSS Align Boxes

Tags: css

I have a footer that has 3 columns of content.  Currently the css is using `float:left`.  I have tried the following but I just cant get it to align vertical and horizontal.

- display block
- display block-inline
- margin: 0 auto

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="column">
    <h3>Information</h3>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="">Delivery Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#footer .column {
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "align vertical and horizontal"?

Comment: @Sheen I am wanting the boxes in the footer to be aligned not the content

Comment: See my new answer.  have tested this here and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
        Information
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>One</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        Information
        <ul>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        Information
        <ul>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<style>

.footer
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:Yellow;
}

.footer .columns
{
    text-align:center;
}

.column
{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline;
    width: 150px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.column ul li{
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

the above will align then horizontally if that's what your question is asking

**edit**

```
<div class="footer" id="footer">
    <div class="column">
        <h3>Information</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Delivery Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

```css
.footer.column{
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I am wanting the boxes in the footer to be aligned not the content

Comment: I want to align http://cl.ly/3f1H1q3k0P370s1V0w3n in the middle of the footer box

Answer (score 1):

You should use container div with position absolute and #footer should have position relative.
Here is the solution code 
http://jsfiddle.net/7Pcag/1/

or more simpler solution http://jsfiddle.net/7Pcag/5/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already have the correct solution, so you might be doing something else wrong.  I adjusted your min-height to 150px and things work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/xkdk9/1/